# After I run docker compose up, my mac returns error stating that it can't find my mix phx.server. How do I show docker where my mix.exs file is?

Tags: docker, macos, elixir, phoenix-framework

When I'm running Docker Compose up, I receive an error

```
** (Mix) The task "phx.server" could not be found
Note no mix.exs was found in the current directory
```

I believe it's the very last step I need to run the project. This is a phoenix/Elixir Docker project. Mix.exs is a top level file in my project, same level as my dockerfile/docker-compose file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM elixir:1.13.1

# Build Args
ARG PHOENIX_VERSION=1.6.6
ARG NODEJS_VERSION=16.x

# Apt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y inotify-tools

# Nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODEJS_VERSION} | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Phoenix
RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix archive.install --force hex phx_new #{PHOENIX_VERSION}
RUN mix local.rebar --force

# App Directory
ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . .
# App Port
EXPOSE 4000

# Default Command
CMD ["mix", "phx.server"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  book-search:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
      POSTGRES_USER: tmclean
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: tmclean
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Let me know what other questions I can answer

Comment: `CMD ["ls"]` would tell you what directory are you in. _Sidenote:_ you are not supposed to start phoenix with `mix phx.server` in production.

Comment: After I built the new images with the CMD["ls"], I received the same error

Comment: Your Dockerfile has no `COPY` command, so I don't see how the `mix.exs` is getting copied to the image. Does it work if you remove the `WORKDIR` line? I'm not sure why you switch to this empty directory.

Comment: Probably it woud make more sense to have `COPY . /app`, but first I would actually build erlang release and put it to the image, because you want to have everything compiled properly in production mode (including assets with digests, for example).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/app
```

You are overwriting the app with a probably non-existant `src` directory. Change it to:

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

and it should work. However, if you do that, there is no point in copying the files in your `Dockerfile`, so you can also remove the

```
COPY . .
```

Alternatively, leave the `COPY` if you want the source files to be in the image, and remove the `volumes` section from the `book-search` service in `docker-compose.yml`.